# How to lemmatize a single word in Swift

Tags: swift, string, nlp

How do you get the stem form of a single word token? Here is my code. It works for some words, but not others.

```
let text = "people" // works
// let text = "geese" // doesn't work
let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lemma])
tagger.string = text
let (tag, range) = tagger.tag(at: text.startIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lemma)
let stemForm = tag?.rawValue ?? String(text[range])
```

However, if I lemmatize the entire text it's able to find all the stem forms of words.

```
let text = "This is text with plurals such as geese, people, and millennia."
let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lemma])
tagger.string = text

var words: [String] = []
tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lemma, options: [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation]) { tag, range in
    let stemForm = tag?.rawValue ?? String(text[range])
    words += [stemForm]
    return true
}

// this be text with plural such as goose person and millennium
words.joined(separator: " ")
```

Also, is it possible to reverse the process and find the plural version of a stem word?

Comment: I'd guess that since `geese` is already the original word, the tagger will just return nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the language of the text before tagging it, it works:

```
tagger.string = text
tagger.setLanguage(.english, range: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex)
let (tag, range) = tagger.tag(at: text.startIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lemma)
```

Without setting a language, the tagger guesses the language. Apparently, just "geese" alone is too little information for it to guess that it is English. If you check `dominantLanguage` without setting the language explicitly, it is apparently Dutch.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it's possible to reverse the process too and get the plural version of the word?

Comment: @BerryBlue I think that question belongs in another post. But make sure you search for existing Stack Overflow questions first!